# How to display the proper data?

Tags: c#, sql

I have 2 datagridviews now i want to select a column named "Name" in the first datagridview and us it as the WHERE in my query to Select values from a table and put it in the other datagridview.

```
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
   cmd = ss.CreateCommand();
   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvAtt.Rows)
   {
     ss.Open();
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
     string Query = "SELECT Signature FROM TBL_Student WHERE Name = '" + 
     row.Cells[4].Value.ToString() + "' ";
     cmd.CommandText = Query;
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     SqlDataAdapter dp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     dp.Fill(dt);
     dgvSign.DataSource = dt;
     ss.Close();
    }
```

but it gives me error when there is null and it is only selecting the first row in the first datagridview.

Answer (score 0):

You create in each `foreach`-loop a new `DataTable` and therefore it will always just have one Value. So you have to create it before the foreach-loop.

And make sure you check the `Values` you want to use before using them. 
With this easy `if`-condition, there won't be any problems.

---

**Edit1:**

This code snippet is working just fine. 
Just change the `ConnectionString` and you are done.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string error;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DATEBASE; User ID=USERNAME; Password=PASSWORD"))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvAtt.Rows)
    {
        string Query = "SELECT Signature FROM TBL_Student WHERE Name = '";
        if (row.Cells.Count >= 4 && row.Cells[4].Value != null)
        {
            Query += row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        }
        Query += "'";

        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);

            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                con.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
dgvSign.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: tried this but it is not displaying data? why is that ?